# Radio button Validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I need to validate radio buttons and I am struggling to find where the problem is coming from.

Basically put, what happens when I submit, it does not validate the form and all it's fields. I know it is this function that is causing the problem, because when it is taken out of the .js file the form validates properly.

Below is the part of my HTML file containing the radio buttons

```
<tr>
    <th align="left">Driver Required: </th>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="Driver" value="Yes" id="radio_error"> Yes
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><br></td>
 <td>
     <input type="radio" name="Driver" value="No" id="radio_error"> No
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr><th><br></th></tr>
     <tr>
         <th align="left">Insurance: </th>
         <td>
             <input type="radio" name="Insurance" value="None" id="radio_error"> None
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><br></td>
      <td>
          <input type="radio" name="Insurance" value="CDW" id="radio_error"> Collision Damage Waiver
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="Insurance" value="LI" id="radio_error"> Liability Insurance
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="Insurance" value="PAI" id="radio_error"> Personal Accident Insurance
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="Insurance" value="PEC" id="radio_error"> Personal Effects Coverage
      </td>
  </tr>
```

The following lines of code is from the .js file. I have a validate function, which I am sure isn't the problem.

```
function checkDriverRadio()
{
    var yesOrNo = "";
    var len = document.ClientForm.Drvier.length;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        if (document.ClientForm.Drvier[i].checked)
        {
            yesOrNo = document.ClientForm.Driver[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!document.ClientForm.Driver.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("radio_error").innerHTML = "No option selected";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("radio_error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}

function checkInsuranceRadio()
{
    var option = "";
    var len = document.ClientForm.Insurance.length;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        if (document.ClientForm.Insurance[i].checked)
        {
            option = document.ClientForm.Insurance[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!document.ClientForm.Insurance.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("radio_error").innerHTML = "No option selected";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("radio_error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats up with document.ClientForm.Drvier.length; ?

Comment: I'm going to need to see more core to be able to help you

Comment: @John it is a bit of a hassle to have the full file on here because indenting problems. I could maybe link a onedrive or dropbox file.

Comment: Fair enough, what’s ClientForm? Im thinking the problem might be there

Comment: @John Apologies the Drvier was a typo.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for me?

Comment: @SirDogManThing: we discourage the use of file lockers and paste boards to supply code - if it does not fit into the question then it is generally considered too broad to ask. Also, please don't add "ASAP" anywhere in the title/question, it is considered poor form here.

Comment: If you have spotted a typo in your code presented here (`Drvier`) then please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misspelling error...

```
if (document.ClientForm.Drvier[i].checked)
    {
        yesOrNo = document.ClientForm.Driver[i].value;
        break;
```

....your file name is Driver not Drvier.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I realize all your radio buttons have the same Id's, Radio buttons are grouped by `name="someName"` which you have done and as mentioned by other answers you have some typographical errors you need to look at. I created a simple validation in this fiddle kindly check it out if it helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/mr_odoom/17xwdL79/